# Apache PDFBox form field with two styles

Tags: pdfbox

I'm using a pdf with editable form fields. When I click on a field and edit the value manually, it apparently uses different style from the one showing the value in non editing mode. If I change font size in default appearance via PDFBox only visual style of field in editing mode changes but not the style of displayed value.

Field in non editing mode:
[image: Field in non editing mode]

field in edit mode:
[image: field in edit mode]

As seen from the pictures, even the font is different.
Do you have any idea how can I change font size of the displayed value?

Comment: Please check whether that field also has rich text formatting information

Comment: I checked it and it isn't Rich Text field.

Comment: In that case please share the PDF for analysis